# Error with repacking boot.img (Android)

Tags: android, linux, build, linux-kernel, boot

I have Nexus 5 with AOSP ROM 4.4.4.

I'm trying to "pull" boot.img from the device, unpack it, edit "init.rc", repack it to boot.img and flash it to the device.

I follow many guides but none of them have the same scenario as I have:

(http://droidcore.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/how-to-edit-initrc-in-android.html and http://www.digitalinternals.com/mobile/android-mmc-mmcblk-partition-layout/259/)

1. The device partition is mmcblck so from `ls -l /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/` I got that the boot is `/dev/block/mmcblk0p19`:

> lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1971-02-28 21:30 boot ->
>   /dev/block/mmcblk0p19

1. I created the boot.img with the command: `cat /dev/block/mmcblk0p19 > /mnt/sdcard/boot.img` and pull this boot.img to my pc. This boot.img is ~23 MB.
2. I `unmkbootimg` the boot.img with the tool in http://droidcore.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/how-to-edit-initrc-in-android.html and got 2 files: `initramfs.cpio.gz` which is ~500 KB and `kernel.gz` which is ~8.4 MB. The details I got are:

> Kernel size 8405280
>
> Kernel address 0x8000
>
> Ramdisk size 498992
>
> Ramdisk address 0x2900000
>
> Secondary size 0
>
> Secondary address 0xf00000
>
> Kernel tags address 0x2700000
>
> Flash page size 2048
>
> Board name is ""
>
> Command line "console=ttyHSL0,115200,n8 androidboot.hardware=hammerhead
>   user_debug=31 maxcpus=2 msm_watchdog_v2.enable=1"
>
> Extracting kernel.gz
>
> ... Extracting initramfs.cpio.gz ...
>
> All done.
>
> ---
>
> To recompile this image, use:
>
> mkbooting --kernel kernel.gz --ramdisk initramfs.cpio.gz --base 0x26fff00 --cmdline 'console=ttyHSL0,115200,n8 androidboot.hardware=hammerhead user_debug=31 maxcpus=2 msm_watchdog_v2.enable=1' -o new_boot.img

4. I unpack `initramfs.cpio.gz` with the command: `gunzip -c initramfs.cpio.gz | sudo sh -c 'cd ../ && cpio -i'` (from http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Build+and+Modify+a+Rootfs) and got many files, init.rc among them. I edited this file.
5. I repack `initramfs.cpio.gz` with the command: `sh -c 'cd ../ && sudo find . | sudo cpio -H newc -o' | gzip -9 > new_initramfs.cpio.gz` and got this file ~500KB.
6. Now I `mkbootimg` those 2 files with the command: `./mkbooting --kernel kernel.gz --ramdisk initramfs.cpio.gz --base 0x26fff00 --cmdline 'console=ttyHSL0,115200,n8 androidboot.hardware=hammerhead user_debug=31 maxcpus=2 msm_watchdog_v2.enable=1' -o new_boot.img` and I got boot.img which is ~8.5 MB
7. Now flash the boot to the device and the device is stuck on the first screen (not boot up)

My questions are:

1. What's wrong?
2. Is that normal that my new boot.img is only 8.5 MB instead of 23 MB (the original)?

Thank you guys!

************* I FOUND THE PROBLEM *************

THE SOLUTION IS:
I used `unmkbootimg` from here: `http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Unmkbootimg`
After I run unmkbootimg I got this comment:

*** WARNING ****
This image is built using NON-standard mkbootimg!
OFF_KERNEL_ADDR is 0xFD908100
OFF_RAMDISK_ADDR is 0x00200100
OFF_SECOND_ADDR is 0xFE800100
Please modify mkbootimg.c using the above values to build your image.

---

so I follow the instructions here: `https://gist.github.com/jberkel/1087757` and now it works!!!

Comment: I've also wanted to to this, but only succeeded on Windows (!) when using [imgutil.exe](http://www.temblast.com/imgutil.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I can't give the answer to the first question, but if I were you I'd skip step 4&5 and verify whether the unmkbootimg/mkbootimg process is correct. Only after it's verified, I till tackle with the cpio process, and finally the init.rc editing.

For the second question, google's official boot.img is 8.64MB, so I guess there is nothing wrong with the size.

Comment: I tried it (skip step 4&5) and it doesn't work as well. Do you know  how they calculate the "base" offset? maybe the problem is there? Thanks!

Comment: I found the problem: The boot.img was build with different offsets (not the default) so I recompile the mkbootimg with the relevant offsets!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @kande, maybe you can share the details, so that other people won't make the same mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's abootimg worked for me. I used the update (-u) option.